# Why do we get extra symmetric terms/factors when applying annihilation operators to multiparticle states of definite momentum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, second-quantization, identical-particles

Sorry for the wordy title, but I wasn't sure how else to express what I want to ask succinctly.

My question is best illustrated with an example. Suppose we are calculating a scattering amplitude in QFT (working in the canonical quantization formalism), where our initial incoming state is  $\left|{i}\right>=\left|{\mathbf{p}}\right>\left|{\mathbf{p}'}\right>$, which is a direct product of two free particle states of definite on-shell momentua $p$ and $p'$. We decompose the scalar field operator $\phi(x)=\phi^{+}(x)+\phi^{-}(x)$ into positive and negative frequency parts, defined as

$$
\phi^{+}(x)=\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{2\omega(\mathbf{p})} a(\mathbf{p})e^{-ip\cdot x}\quad\text{and}\quad\phi^{-}(x)=\int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{2\omega(\mathbf{p})} a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{p})e^{+ip\cdot x}
$$

where $\omega(\mathbf{p})=p^{0}=\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^{2}+m^{2}}$ is the on-shell momentum condition, and $a(\mathbf{p})$ and its conjugate are the annihilation and creation operators for the scalar field. With these conventions, we find that

$$
\phi^{+}(x)\left|{\mathbf{p}}\right>=\int\frac{d^{3}p'}{(2\pi)^{3}2\omega(\mathbf{p}')}e^{-ip'\cdot x}a(\mathbf{p}')a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{p})\left|{0}\right>=\int d^{3}p'e^{-ip'\cdot x}\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p}')\left|{0}\right>=e^{-ip\cdot x}\left|{0}\right>
$$

for example. My confusion stems from when we apply two copies of $\phi^{+}(x)$ to our initial state $\left|{i}\right>=\left|{\mathbf{p}}\right>\left|{\mathbf{p}'}\right>$. The notes I'm following state that

$$
\phi^{+}(x)^{2}\left|{\mathbf{p}}\right>\left|{\mathbf{p}'}\right>=2e^{-i(p+p')\cdot x}\left|0\right>
$$

which makes sense intuitively to me - we have two possible permutations of choosing which of each of the two states to apply each of the two field operators to, so we get an extra factor of two. However, if we follow the calculation through similarly to the single state case, I can't see why we get this factor of two. Why do we not choose just one of the states to apply one of our operators to arbitrarily, and then apply the other to the remaining one necessarily?

Another example of this would be from [David Tong's QFT notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html), page 59, in the nucleon scattering example. We have the following calculation:

[image]

In the third line, exactly analogously to my simpler example above, why in each of the terms in parentheses do we have the two exponential terms, with the $x_{i}$'s permuted in the arguments, as opposed to just one of the possible permutations? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**: Define $$|p,p^\prime\rangle \equiv \sqrt{2E_p} \sqrt{2E_{p^\prime}}\, a^\dagger(p)\, a^\dagger(p^\prime) |0\rangle \quad , $$
but take care since sometimes different conventions are used. Then, for the case of bosons, make use of the commutation relations
$$[a(p),a^\dagger(q)] = (2\pi)^3 \delta(p-q) $$

and the fact that $a(q)|0\rangle = 0$ to compute

$$ a(q) \,a(k) \, a^\dagger(p) \, a^\dagger(p^\prime) |0\rangle \quad .$$

Comment: Thank you, that sorts it. My confusion stemmed from the definition of the state $\left|p;p'\right>$ - I had been treating it as a quantum mechanical tensor product of two states, rather than the construction which you define here.

Comment: @LC400 Great. Yeah, in cases like this one, it often pays out to go back to the definition (which I guess you will find in the notes you are following; in any case, David Tong uses this definition and convention too, cf. equation 2.64).